# Appcelerator / Titanium - Are Javascript variables polluting the global scope in controller files?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm new to Appcelerator and Titianium Alloy, and I wandering how the global scope works in the controller Javascript files.

It is still best practice to attach all of your variables to a single global object within these files? In a lot of tutorials it seems that they are just declaring variables with quite common names right in the file with no closure of the scope.

Comment: the controller has a scope of it's own I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your global variables and functions in your `app/alloy.js`:

```
 Alloy.Globals.myModule = require("myModule");

 Alloy.Globals.myFunction = function(e){
     // your logic function
 };
```

Comment: So individual controllers have their own scope?

Comment: Generally you can set your global variables to anywhere.
but I would like to set my primary func at there.

you can read at docs : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers-section-34636384_AlloyControllers-InitializerFile%28alloy.js%29

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.